# Move a Facebook chat window horizontally

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

In Facebook I sometimes read my news feed while chatting.

I also have chats that I don't want to close because I haven't replied yet.

This leads to situations where the chat window of the person I am currently talking to covers the news feed, making reading less pleasant:

[image: Chat and news overlapping in Facebook]

QUESTION: What is the most convenient way to move Bob's discussion further right, without closing my reduced conversations with Joe and Ann?

Answer (score -1):

Stack unopened chats on the top of one another OR keep them in a single bulk like window shows multiple opens folders in taskbar.

Comment: Could you please describe step-by-step how to stack the unopened chats? A screenshot would be great too. Thanks! :-)